# How to bind a comment form to one pot without a choice (Django)

Tags: python, django

> When writing a comment under the article, it becomes possible to
> choose which post to bring the comment to. How to make comments
> automatically attach to the post under which it is written.
>
> ```
> **views.py**
>
>     
>     class AddCommentView(CreateView):
>         model  = Comment
>         template_name = 'main/post_detail.html'
>         form_class = CommentForm
>         #fields = '__all__' 
>         success_url = reverse_lazy('barbers')
> ```

> ```
>     **models.py**
>
>    
>
>      class Post(models.Model):
>           photo       = models.ImageField(upload_to='media/photos/',null=True, blank=True)
>           name_barber = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=True)
>           description = models.TextField()
>         
>           def __str__(self):
>               return self.description[:10]
>         
>         
>         class Comment(models.Model):
>           post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
>           name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
>           body = models.TextField(null=True)
>           add_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
>         
>         
>           def __str__(self):
>               return '%s - %s' % (self.post, self.name)
>
> **forms.py**
>
>    
>
>  class CommentForm(ModelForm):
>         class Meta:
>             model = Comment
>             fields = ( 'post', 'name', 'body')
> ```

Comment: Is the primary key of the `Post` to which you want to link it in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `post` field from the `CommentForm`:

```
class CommentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('name', 'body')
```

In the path, you specify the primary key of the post to bind the comment to:

```
path('<int:post_pk>/comment', AddCommentView.as_view(), name='comment')
```

then in the `AddCommentView`, you can link the object to the post represented by this primary key in the [**`.form_valid(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid):

```
class AddCommentView(CreateView):
    model  = Comment
    template_name = 'main/post_detail.html'
    form_class = CommentForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('barbers')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.post_id = self.kwargs['post_pk']
        return super().form_valid(form)
```